# Querying Django on a derived field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Using Django 1.8

I have an unmanaged model that points to a view in the db and I'm trying to return a queryset based on a derived field.

Here is a basic example of the model structure:

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    book_id = models.IntegerField()
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True) # Can join to Publisher.publisher_name
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True) # Can join to Sku.sku

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'vw_book'


class Sku(models.Model):
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey('myapp.Publisher')


class Publisher(models.Model):
    publisher_name = models.CharField(max_lenth=20)
    region = models.ForeignKey('myapp.Region')


class Region(models.Model):
    region_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

I'm looking for a way to return a queryset of Book based on the region, derived from the publisher as the preferred field and then the sku. It is possible for these fields in Book to refer to different region fields as the data is unlcean and has been derived from multiple sources. I can add a method to the Book model to derive the region, but trying to get a queryset from this is too slow.

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'vw_book'

    def get_region(self):
        if not self.publisher:
            if not self.sku:
                return ''
            try:
               sku = Sku.objects.get(sku=self.sku)
               return sku.publisher.region.region_name
            except Sku.DoesNotExist:
               return ''
         try:
             publisher = Publisher.objects.get(publisher_name=self.publisher)
             return publisher.region.region_name
         except Publisher.DoesNotExist:
             return ''


region_dict = {}
for book in Book.objects.all():
    region_dict.setdefault(book.get_region(), []).append(book.book_id)

Book.objects.filter(book_id__in=region_dict.get('UK', []))
```

I am unable to add an extra field to the Book model. Is there a more efficient way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would filter the skus and then filter books based on the skus you receive

```
skus = Sku.objects.filter(publisher__region__region_name=region).values_list('sku', flat=True)
Book.objects.filter(sku__in=skus)
```

You can do the same with publishers if need be and do an Or query.

```
 .filter(Q(publisher__in=publishers) |Q(sku__in=skus))
```